# Use Twig to render HTML email body for SwiftMailer

Tags: theming, 8, emails

I have a custom module with a controller where I'm building a PDF file with a node's data that will be mailed to a certain user.

I have installed the [SwiftMailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) module and I have been able to produce my desired outcome, but it isn't very clean.

I was wondering if I could use a `twig` template to build the body of my HTML email. Is there anyway I can make use of Drupal's Twig Extension for this purpose?

I already created a `email.html.twig` file with the layout I need and I already have a `$parameters` array with all the variables I need to use in the template, but as SwiftMailer uses an HTML string in the [`setBody()`](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-the-body-content) method, I'm trying to use Twig to produce the HTML I need to use there. Any thoughts?

Please note that I don't want to use the twig template *in* my module ( to show a Drupal page or something), but rather have Twig render an HTML string I can use with SwiftMailer.
Also, the instructions for the SwiftMailer module regarding theming are rather confusing for me and they are for Drupal 7, so I don't see how I can make use of them in my case.

Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that's possible. It works exactly as if you would render something for the page.

After preparing your render array like you always do, all you need to do is call the renderPlain() method of the renderer service, that gives you a string (Actually, a Markup object containing a string).

`contact_mail()` does exactly that, the relevant part:

```
$build = entity_view($contact_message, 'mail');
$message['body'][] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

PS: The fact it is a Markup object is important, do not try to cast it to a string.

Comment: I added a `#theme` key to the build array to use a custom twig theme for the body. Although my outgoing mail has the content-type "text/html", the body part seems to be handled as plain text, because html tags are removed.How do I get around this?

Comment: I am also having this same exact issue. No matter what I do, I can't get the body to render as HTML. The template works fine, but the actual body variable doesn't render as HTML, just plain text with the markup rendered as plain text.

Comment: use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup; and then Markup::create($body) in order to give the method what it wanted which is instanceof MarkupInterface